# Automate cadaver error handling

Tags: svn, webdav

I would like to use **cadaver** for releasing file to SVN:

```
{ echo mkdir $VERSION
  echo cd $VERSION
  echo put CHANGES
  echo put README
  echo quit
} | cadaver http://$HOST:$PORT/frs/$PROJ
```

I set policy for possible **$VERSION** values in **pre-commit** hook. So **mkdir** and **cd** command can fail but **put** was complited in wrong (root) dir.

How can I prevent this error?

Another free WEBDAV client with possibility error of handling also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**expect** is my friend. With is inconvinient for **Ant Java**. But reasonably good for **GNU Make**.

Comment: Good that you found the solution, +1